# Module not found error ; Cannot find module '.../Hello-World/artifacts/contracts/Hello-World.sol/HelloWorld.json'

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

When I try deploying my contract it keeps saying cannot find module and my contract path is written correctly in my code. here is my interact.js file I use to communicate with my contract.

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY; //get from alchemy
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = process.env.CONTRACT; //deployed contract address
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY; //metamask

const contract = require('.../Hello-World/artifacts/contracts/Hello-World.sol/HelloWorld.json');

// provider - Alchemy
const alchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(network="goerli", API_KEY);

// signer - you
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, alchemyProvider);

// contract instance
const helloWorldContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, contract.abi, signer);

async function main() {

    const message = await helloWorldContract.message();
    console.log("the message is "+ message);

    const tx = await helloWorldContract.update("Good Bye, World!");
    await tx.wait();

    const nmessage = await helloWorldContract.message();
    console.log("the new message is "+ nmessage);
}

main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

the error shown after running npx hardhat run scripts/interact.js --network goerli

Error: Cannot find module '.../Hello-World/artifacts/contracts/Hello-World.sol/HelloWorld.json'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\ASUS\Hello-World\scripts\interact.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\ASUS\Hello-World\scripts\interact.js:7:18)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)

Comment: try,  "npx hardhat clean" and try again.

Comment: It is still giving the same error as stated above

Answer (score 0):

At first, I didn't go through your code, now after having a second look, looks like you are trying to interact with an already deployed contract, in that case, you are having a wrong approach.

You can make that easy by using the following line rather than importing the artifacts file.

```
contractInstance = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
      "contractName",
      contractAddress
    );
```

I believe you know the rest on how to use the contract instance to call the functions. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found that in my deploy.js I made a typo when naming my contract (`const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");`) as well as other locations where you write the contract name. I would recommend you double check typos. Hope this helps.